# automating release pipeline creation Azure Devops

Tags: automation, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I have one DevOps project which has a build pipeline and a release pipeline. creation of build pipeline, DevOps project, container registry, service connection, and Kubernetes cluster is automated using terraform, ARM templates and AZCLI. I could not find any way to store the release pipeline as a code. Is there any way to do that? I want to know how other people are dealing with this? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Did you look at multi-stage YAML pipelines?

Comment: @DanielMann well This is the closest thing to what I was looking for. Though it does not create a separate release pipeline but gets the job done. thanks for input. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could not find any way to store the release pipeline as a code. Is
>   there any way to do that? I want to know how other people are dealing
>   with this? Is there something I am missing?

Looks like you're looking for [multi-stage Yaml pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/multi-stage-pipelines-experience?view=azure-devops) like **Daniel** commented above. For now, we can't directly create release pipeline as Yaml format, but we can use multi-stage Yaml for both CI and CD.

To use that option, we need to enable the **Multi-stage
pipelines** in **Preview Features**.

[image]

[image]

You may get more useful info from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58898792/10910450) and [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/). Hope it helps.