# Is there a way do undo pipeline deletion in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

After a release pipeline is deleted, is there a way to undo that deletion? One of our critical pipelines was deleted and while we had backed up the definition, it would be nice to know if Azure DevOps has the undo functionality built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **this is not supported at this time**.

See this [existing similar thread (Can I Recover A Deleted Release Definition?)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/74423/can-i-recover-a-deleted-release-definition.html)

As a workaround, you can [export your release pipeline definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52465280/7073340) just for the safety.

Comment: We've been backing up the exported definition in our repo, hence how I was able to get it back. Still, I voted for the feature to be added in the link provided (thanks for that BTW).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it on my private collection, this is not supported. Sadly there is no recycle bin similar to the work items bin from which you could restore the deleted definition. As a workaround for the future, what you can do is to regularly export all the definitions as json (click breadcrumbs, then export, this can also easily be automated via the rest api) and save them somewhere (e.g. in source control). That way you at least always have sth at hand, even if slightly outdated.

Comment: We had an export of the most recent version in source control, so it wasn't a big deal to get back. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: 1+ for your contribution with an explanation and workaround